# BootStrap : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have just started off with BootStrap, however stranded with
**`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function`** error message. Could someone let me know what went missing with this code?

Since then, have referred to multiple similar questions but to no avail.

***`home_page.html`***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Health Insurance</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">

</head>

<body>
  <form role="form">

  <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="insuredName">Insured Name :</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="insuredName" placeholder="Insured Name">
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="rel_PolicyHolder">Relation with Policy Holder :</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="rel_PolicyHolder" placeholder="Relation with Policy Holder"> <br />
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>

    
<div class="container" >
<div class="col-sm-4" style="height:130px; align:right">
                            
            <div class='input-group date'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker9' /> 
                    <span class="input-group-addon"> 
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>

            <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script></script>
            <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker9').datetimepicker({
            viewMode: 'years'
            });
        });
      </script>
     </div>

     </div>
    </div>

 </form>

 </body>
</html>
```

All the files are placed under **`WebContent`** folder in Eclipse but ***`outside`*** of **`META-INF`** and **`WEB-INF`** folder.

**Files under** **`css`** **folder**

- bootstrap-theme.css
- bootstrap-theme.css.map
- bootstrap-theme.min.css
- bootstrap.css
- bootstrap.css.map
- bootstrap.min.css
- enhanced.css
- jquery-ui.css
- ui.daterangepicker.css

**Files under** **`fonts`** **folder**

- glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
- glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
- glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
- glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
- glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2

**Files under** **`js`** **folder**

- bootstrap-datepicker.min.css
- bootstrap-datepicker.min.js
- bootstrap.js
- bootstrap.min.js
- date.js
- enhance.min.js
- fileinput.jquery.js
- jquery-1.11.2.min.js
- jquery-1.8.3.min.js
- jquery-1.9.0.min.js
- jquery-ui.js
- npm.js

**Error-message**

> `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function`
>
> `(anonymous function) @ home_page.html:82`
>
> `m.Callbacks.j @ jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2`
>
> `m.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2`
>
> `m.extend.ready @ jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2`
>
> `J @ jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2`

***Any guidance would be noteworthy***

Comment: You're loading `bootstrap-datepicker` but using `datetimepicker`. These are two seperate packages.

Comment: It's `$( ... ).datepicker({ options })`. Read https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest (it's also on the project readme)

Comment: @Andy nope, I'm using that project in BS3 as I type this, and it's most definitely `datepicker`. - That repo contains both 2 and 3 code.

Comment: Are you using `http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/`?

Comment: @h2ooooooo - Error is no more showing now. 
`Could you please help me now to realign the date-picker text box so that it goes in tandem with the previous row text-box.`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are using `datetimepicker` when it should be `datepicker`. As per the [docs](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Try this and it should work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker9').datepicker({
      viewMode: 'years'
    });
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: **Perfect !!!**   Error is gone...  please help me now to realign the date-picker text box so that it goes in tandem with the previous row text-box.

Comment: NIce it works but is it providing date object. I checked its providing string. Will you help on this ?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem, you have to load first the Moment.js file!

```html
<script src="path/moment.js"></script>
<script src="path/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit late but I know it will help someone:

If you are using `datetimepicker` make sure you include the right CSS and JS files. `datetimepicker` uses(Take note of their names);

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css

and

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js

On the above question asked by @mindfreak,The main problem is due to the imported files.

Answer (score 0):

You guys copied the wrong code.

Go into the "/build" folder and grab the jquery.datetimepicker.full.js or jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js if you want the minified version.
It should fix it! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old version of the date picker js. Upgrade datepicker js with latest one.

Replace your bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js file with this will work..

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.3/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. Solution for me was to remove links to Vue.js files. Vue.js and JQuery have some conflicts in datepicker and datetimepicker functions.