# Getting TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am scratching my head at this issue. I am trying to use bootstrap datetimepicker add-on to have a nice dynamic calendar but Firefox and Chrome are giving me the same error: TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function. The calendar never appears of course.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js">    </script>
```

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong? The order or something?

EDIT: I am trying to call DateTimePicker as documentation on http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ , not DatePicker as in the suggested answer.

Comment: Check if jQuery is loaded. `~/Scripts` vs `/scripts`

Comment: And make sure all of your other js files are loading, check the browser console.

Comment: Tested with both ~ and without, no success. Steve, verified the console and all seems in place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BootStrap : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29963634/bootstrap-uncaught-typeerror-datetimepicker-is-not-a-function)

Comment: check this answer, may be you get idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29963634/bootstrap-uncaught-typeerror-datetimepicker-is-not-a-function

Comment: I can call DatePicker yes, but shouldn't it be DateTimePicker as per documentation on http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ ?

Comment: If you're not getting any other errors on the console, it probably because it can't find `bootstrap-datetimepicker.js`. You might have downloaded the `bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js`?

Comment: Verified the scripts folders and both files are in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check here it works well https://jsfiddle.net/vvmhbykw/ with your code:

```
$(function() {
 $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
});
```

Try using different script versions or ones that I used in fiddle.

Comment: Tested scripts in same order and everything. Something must be clashing with the jquery internally. *sigh*

Comment: Only this: Register:148 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function(anonymous function) @ Register:148i @ jquery-2.2.0.min.js:2j.fireWith @ jquery-2.2.0.min.js:2n.extend.ready @ jquery-2.2.0.min.js:2J @ jquery-2.2.0.min.js:2
abp.js:285 DEBUG:

Comment: strange.. maybe conflict with other scripts causes this, if you have them