# Bootstrap datepicker showing date only, No time

Tags: javascript, css, datetime, bootstrap-4, datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker to pick date and time, but the calendar does not show the time picked. See bellow code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#start_date').datepicker({
        format: "dd M yyyy hh:ii a",
        autoclose: true
    });
});
```

It sets the value as `12 Nov 2020 hh:ii a`. It is not recognizing hours and minutes. What I am doing wrong here?

I also tested above code for format `dd MM YYYY HH:mm` suggested in the answers, but still not working. Now it is print `18 November YYYY HH:11`

Comment: `ii` should be `mm` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your datepicker format is wrong.

Instead, you should use `dd mm yyyy`, where:

**yyyy**: `4-digit year`

**mm**: `2-digit month (where January is 01 and December is 12)`

**dd**: `2-digit date (0 to 31)`

Also, if you are using a **datepicker**, you won't be able to extract **time** from it.

You can read more about it [here](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

EDIT: For Bootstrap V4, you can use [Tempus Dominus](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/) as date and time picker.

Comment: I don't know how to get that. I using exact same code. I am using `bootstrap-datepicker`

Comment: Ok. Using `dd mm yyyy`, were you able to get a properly formatted date?

Comment: That's because you are using a **date** picker. In order to get date and time, you must use a datetime picker.

Comment: How to use that ? If i use .datetimepicker(), `Uncaught TypeError: $(…).datetimepicker is not a function`. Same I found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29963634/bootstrap-uncaught-typeerror-datetimepicker-is-not-a-function

Comment: You must use a third-party datetimepicker. Bootstrap only have a datepicker. Which bootstrap version are you using, by the way?

Comment: Bootstrap v4.5.0

Comment: Now time selection model popup is working but calendar to select date is not working

Comment: $('#start_date').datetimepicker({
          format: 'DD MMM yyyy hh:mm A',
          keepOpen: false
        });

Comment: <div class="date">
                  <input type="text datetimepicker-input" class="form-control" data-date="12-02-2012" id="start_date" data-toggle="datetimepicker" data-target="#start_date">
                </div>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224423/discussion-between-brhaka-and-jai).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with first answer, but you can try again with YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ and check if it this help.